# Best practice for assigning key for different widgets?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been looking for controlling each widget in a page using a separate key. Can anyone suggest me best way for that?
I tried in Form like

```
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
Form(
key: formKey,
),
```

But I am confused while working with Container, Card, and others widget.
Can any suggest what should I follow and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need formKey for Container, Card or any other widget which is not related with .

If you create Form Widget, you need to give it a TextFormField child, which inherits FormState.

The thing is here, probably you'll have multiple TextFormField widgets, so instead of creating and handling them one by one keys for each TextFormField, you create Form Widget to group your TextFormFields, then assign formKey once and use it at all.

Your formKey has no business with other type of widgets.

Explainer code:

```
  Widget buildFormTree() {
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    String text1;
    String text2;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
//            key: asd, //No need
                onSaved: (text) {
                  text1 = text;
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
//            key: qwe, // No need
                onSaved: (text) {
                  text2 = text;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Save Forms'),
          onPressed: () {
            ///to trigger onSaved callback
            formKey.currentState.save();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: And how do I declare key for the separate container if I need one?

Comment: And thank you very much for your precious information.

Comment: You won't need Container key unless you have an advanced purpose of doing so. However, you can simply assign you are page name combined with container. If there are multiples, also assign a number that incrementing by each Container. For example:
this a key for only Container inside HomePage => Key('HomePageContainer') and this is yet another key for second Container of LoginScreen => Key('LoginScreenContainer2'). To how assign => Container(key: Key('...')).
There is only one rule while creating Key, DO NOT CREATE DUPLICATE, that's all, so be sure you have uniqe page names also.

Comment: I was confused about declaring it. But now that is clear. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome. If your question is solved, please don't forget to confirm my answer as accepted answer and thumbs up :)